# Does session restart each time when reload page in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-variables

Does session restart each time in laravel when reload page? In the below experiment, I get the `false` from the first dump each time when reload page:

```
dump($request->session()->has('someSessionVariable')); // false
$request->session()->put('someSessionVariable', 'value');
dump($request->session()->has('someSessionVariable')); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Laravel under 5.3 require you to use

```
Session::save();
```

Alternatively if that doesn't work, try changing the cookie name

```
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
```

to

```
'cookie' => 'myapp_session',
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I use laravel 5.5.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu I assume my solutions didn't work. Try using the session facade instead of function. Ex: Session::put('someSessionVariable', 'value') and Session::has('someSessionVariable')